# Is it possible to do astral travel?

Tags: esp, psychics, meditation

Psychic-Medium [Kimbery Bunch](http://www.kimberlybunch.com/) claims in [a video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7oKnOo9kGY8) meditation can help you to astral travel, remote view or to have bilocation abilities.

This Video claims that she can "astral travel" spiritually come out of the body see her own body from outside, "remote view" She can "spiritually" see exactly what her husband (or boy friend) do when he is physically away.

Is it all real or possible to do?  Has anyone researched it or do we have any proof?

Comment: There is a long running research project on a similar claim of near-death experiences where people who return to life describe looking down at their bodies in the hospital. As a test, some doctors have left strange images on high shelves which would not be visible from the bed to see if they are included in the description of looking down at oneself. I read an article on the experiment, but I don't know if they have published their results yet.

Comment: Is not astral travel, remote view and bilocation kinda the same thing? Out of body experiences.

Comment: I doubt it. Randi's site mentions one research paper on the topic that initially said remote viewing was possible, but the paper was later debunked. http://www.randi.org/encyclopedia/remote%20viewing.html

Comment: It's not real unless "astral travel" is another word for "daydreaming". Some people can control even their sleep dreams to some extent. I suspect Kim Bunch *believes* she has this ability, but she's fooling herself. Though if "remote viewing" worked, winning Randi's million dollar prize would be an excellent use of it.

Comment: By the way, I remember about 5-6 years ago there was some guy in Britain (Cambridge?) which was planning to do experiments in reanimation facilities by placing pictures on the shelves, facing up so that patient wouldn't see them; later, if survived, the patient would be asked to describe those. I think the name of the person started with P (Perina? Parnell?)... It seems like it never worked out as I didn't hear anything else. Anyone has any information about this?

Comment: Needs a definition for astral travel (seems to be too fuzzy to be disprovable).

Comment: Good question.. I heard this was used to practice in Satya yug (first yug in Hindu calendar) by saints.